# How to add a class img-responsive to RTE in Sitecore 8.x

Tags: richtext-editor

I would like to add an option to change class on an image that is inserted into the RTE of the content item. In particularly I would like to add bootstrap class "img-responsive".

**So what i have done:**

Added bootstrap.css to the directory

Changed Sitecore.config to point to the bootstrap.css

```
<setting name="WebStylesheet" value="/sitecore/shell/Controls/Rich Text Editor/bootstrap.css" />
```

Edited Website\sitecore\shell\Controls\Rich Text Editor\ToolsFile.xml

```
<classes>
    <class name="Bootstrap Img Responsive" value=".img-responsive"/>    
</classes>
```

Nothing shows up in the RTE. What have I missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pointing to the entire `bootstrap.css` is a bit overkill. (And I suspect Sitecore / Telerik is having a hard time parsing it.) What you should do is ignore the `ToolsFile.xml` entirely (make sure the `<classes>` element is empty), and point the `WebStylesheet` setting to a custom CSS file that only includes classes that should be exposed for selection.

Since you will be including `bootstrap.css` in your layout, you can leave the class selectors empty in your custom editor CSS:

```
a.blue-button {}

a.red-button {}

img.img-responsive {}
```

You could also add your editor-specific styling in there, or you could use the technique described in [this blog post](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/user-specific-or-multi-site-specific-css-styles-in-sitecore-rich-text-editor/) to add other CSS files to the editor.

An important point here is that the RTE in Sitecore hasn't been getting much love. One [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37150257/1327412) you'll likely run into is that if you right-click your image and select "Properties", the CSS class list in the dialog will be empty. I've never been able to find a workaround for that. Other elements like tables and links work as expected. Let us know if you figure out a fix. Meanwhile, the "Apply CSS Class" dropdown which is part of the toolbar at least works as expected.

[image: CSS Class Toolbar]

Finally, you can still set your classes in `ToolsFile.xml`, which will allow you to present user-friendly names instead of direct CSS class names. But then, you will need to keep both CSS and XML in sync.

Answer (score 2):

Another option you might have, is if you want to add class="img-responsive" to all images added via the RichText Editor, you can do this programmatically by patching the saveRichTextContent pipeline.  Also by going this approach, you can automatically clear out any height/widths that could cause images from being responsive as well.  Example of what I did is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <saveRichTextContent>
                <processor type="Site.Components.Pipelines.FormatImagesRichText, Site.Components"></processor>
            </saveRichTextContent>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This will just append an additional pipeline onto the SaveRichTextContent Processor.  Then use the code below with the HTML Agility Pack to add/remove the html you need on the images added via the rich text editor.

```
namespace Site.Components.Pipelines
{
    public class FormatImagesRichText
    {
        public void Process(SaveRichTextContentArgs args)
        {
            args.Content = FormatImages(args.Content);
        }

        private string FormatImages(string content)
        {
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(content);

            if (doc == null || !doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml.Contains("img"))
                return content;

            foreach (var img in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img"))
            {
                // Remove Image Width/Height + Append img-responsive class
                HtmlNode imgNode = img;

                imgNode = RemoveAttribute(imgNode, "height");
                imgNode = RemoveAttribute(imgNode, "width");

                HtmlAttribute attrClass = imgNode.Attributes["class"];

                if (attrClass != null)
                {
                    if (!attrClass.Value.Contains("img-responsive"))
                    {
                        // c# 6 interpolated
                        attrClass.Value = $"{attrClass.Value} img-responsive";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    imgNode.Attributes.Add("class", "img-responsive");
                }

                // Remove Height & Width from Styles Tag
                HtmlAttribute attrStyle = imgNode.Attributes["style"];

                if (attrStyle != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(attrStyle.Value))
                {
                    string style = attrStyle.Value;

                    Regex regex = new Regex(@"(max-width|max-height|width|height)(.*?)(;)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                    style = regex.Replace(style, string.Emtpy);

                    imgNode.Attributes["style"].Value = style.Trim();
                }
            }

            return doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
        }

        private HtmlNode RemoveAttribute(HtmlNode htmlNode, string attribute)
        {
            HtmlAttribute imgAttribute = htmlNode.Attributes[attribute];

            if (imgAttribute != null)
            {
                htmlNode.Attributes.Remove(imgAttribute);
            }

            return htmlNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will add it to all the images, I would like it to be only on a specific images. so for example if I insert an image into the RTE, i want to select it and they apply a class from the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

For the RTE in Sitecore (Telerik RadEditor), it's a one or the other type of scenario. So, you can either use the "WebStyleSheet" setting in Sitecore, or you can modify the RTE's ToolsFile.xml to add your own custom classes. I have a blog post about this [here](http://www.symsoftsolutions.com/Blog/List/Sitecore-Rich-Text-Editor-Styles). I suspect this may be your issue.

Also note that if you modify the ToolsFile.xml file, you will likely run into issues when you perform a Sitecore upgrade, because the file may get overwritten. In my experience, it is better to generate a style sheet specifically for classes needed in the RTE, use the "WebStyleSheet" Sitecore setting to load that style sheet, and not touch the RTE's ToolsFile.xml.

Comment: Your tutorial, shows exactly what I have accomplished, and what I have written in my question. Your answer is not helpful. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

A method I much prefer for user-friendliness is to create a new paragraph type in the RTE Profile:

[image: custom paragraph type]

It looks like this in the Rich Text Editor window:

[image: rich text editor window]

This way you can choose the type of DOM element you want and can specify multiple classes.

Comment: I tried it before, if your users are not careful, they will mess up the whole site.

Comment: Any use of the rich text editor whatsoever can mess up the whole site :)